# Failed to install gitlab-runner: Init already exists

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed gitlab-runner via `sudo apt install gitlab-runner`, configured it according to [the tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) and it worked well.

Now I want to change the user of the gitlab-runner. So I stop the service with `service gitlab-runner stop` and try to change the user via

```
sudo gitlab-runner install --user=my-user --working-directory=/home/my-user
```

I get following error message:

> FATAL: Failed to install gitlab-runner: Init already exists: /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service

How to proceed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Rename the init file with

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service  /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service.bak
   ```
2. and execute again

   ```
   sudo gitlab-runner install --user=my-user --working-directory=/home/my-user
   ```
3. cleanup the backup file

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service.bak
   ```

Finally you can start the runner again with `service gitlab-runner start`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove this file:

`rm /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service`

Or:

`gitlab-runner uninstall`

And then install gitlab-runner again.